# Como criar um gráfico de médias e desvio padrão em um conjunto de dados que inclui valores ausentes (NAs)

Tags: r

Olá!

Trabalho com bioacústica e estou tentando criar um gráfico de médias por espécie utilizando a função lineplot.CI do pacote sciplot, mas não consigo fazer com que o R ignore os valores ausentes (NA). 
Quando faço o gráfico para as durações de notas, tudo vai bem pois a variável DeltaTime não inlui NAs:

```
library(sciplot)
# Note duration
lineplot.CI(dados$especie, dados$DeltaTime, las=1, type="p",
        xlab="Espécie", ylab="Duração nota", main="Duração nota",
        ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x)-sd(x), mean(x)+sd(x)))
```

[image: Duração da nota por espécie]

Quando tento utilizar a mesma função para a variável PeakFreq, por outro lado, as barras de desvio padrão só aparecem para a espécie que não possui nenhum NA:

```
lineplot.CI(dados$especie, dados$PeakFreq, las=1, type="p",
        xlab="Espécie", ylab="Frequência dominante", main="Frequência 
        dominante",
        ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x)-sd(x), mean(x)+sd(x)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei alterar a função de várias maneiras e procurei bastante na internet, mas não obtive sucesso. Alguma ideia de como solucionar esse problema?

obs.: A função não tem problemas em ignorar os NAs quando consideramos apenas o erro padrão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que explicitamente pedir para as funções `mean()` e `sd()` ignorar os `NA`, passando o argumento `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
lineplot.CI(dados$especie, dados$DeltaTime, las=1, type="p",
            xlab="Espécie", ylab="Duração nota", main="Duração nota",
            ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)-sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)+sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```